# How to format the code with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio

How can I format the code with keyboard shortcut
I usualy used  Ctrl S in dart files
but in some files dont work , and i see youtuber make it easy in keyboard but no one say how.

Comment: Which tool you are using VS Code or Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code enable `Format On Save` setting

[image: Format On Save]

Answer (score 0):

To format your code in the current source code window, use Cmd+Option+L (on Mac) or Ctrl+Alt+L (on Windows and Linux)